# How to submit multiple forms data all at once in React?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik

I have 10 components displayed as a side nav list items. Each component is a form (Formik, Material, Yup). When the user clicks on one of the items he goes to a corresponding form page, he can fill out the forms but I want to submit the entire data in a single go (all 10 forms at once).

The problem here is as soon as the user navigates from one form to the other the data get lost. I am not sure how to handle it, any leads?

Answer (score 0):

In my view, if you want to submit all form data in one time you should store all data in 10 forms in their parent component. When the user navigates to other pages, your data will be in the parent component. But I think it's not a good way because the parent component stored a lot of data, it causes poor performance. Why do you want to submit all forms at one time?

Comment: Yes, it can have potential performance issues but the functionality is as such - to capture the values of form fields that the user has filled out and later when the user hits submit whole data should get saved.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of storing the form data in a store? Then each form submit updates the value in the store and one final submit gathers all the data into one data form element and submits to the server?

Comment: Pretty much followed the same approach with React Context though. Thanks!